# Linked Lists in C++ functions and methods

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm taking a C++ class at school and we are now talking about linked lists.  The professor gave us a source file with "Insert First," "Traverse," and "Free List" functions written and working along with a main method to test and demonstrate them.  Our homework assignment was to create four new functions:

1) "Count Target"- count how many times a Node with a target value occurs in the list

2) "In Order"- returns 1 if list is in ascending order (or if it is empty or has only one Node) and 0 if not

3) "Delete First"- Deletes first Node in list and returns next Node (which is the new first Node).  If list has only one Node list should be made empty and Null is returned.  If list is already empty nothing is done and Null is returned.

4) "Insert Last"- creates list by inserting Nodes at the end of the list rather than the front.

So far it seems like the only function I wrote which works is "Delete First."  All the others are not working as far as I can tell and I don't know why.  "Insert Last" causes the following error:

> "The program '[8256] Project9.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0)."

I'm not sure if this is useful or not to note; before I was getting a different error which is no longer appearing and I don't know why (though I have been fiddling with this for the last several hours...)...

"In Order" also causes a breakdown of some kind, and "Count Target" doesn't actually cause the program to crash, yet it doesn't do what it is meant to either.  Any and all help and insight into these troubling dilemmas would be very much appreciated...thanks in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct NODE
{
    struct NODE *link;
    int value;
};  
typedef struct NODE Node;

int countTarget(Node *start, int target){
    int count = 0;
    while (start != NULL)
    {
        if (start->value == target)
            count++;
        start = start->link;
    }
    return count;
}

int inOrder(Node *start){
    int inOrder = 1;
    int temp;
    while (start != NULL)
    {
        temp = start->value;
        start = start->link;
        if (start->value < temp){
            inOrder = 0;
            break;
        }
    }
    return inOrder;
}

Node *deleteFirst(Node **ptrToHeadPtr){
    if (*ptrToHeadPtr != NULL){
        Node* temp = *ptrToHeadPtr;
        *ptrToHeadPtr = (*ptrToHeadPtr)->link;
        free(temp);
    }
    return *ptrToHeadPtr;
}

Node *insertLast(Node **ptrToHeadPtr, int val)
{
    Node *node = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    node->value = val;
    (*ptrToHeadPtr)->link = node;
    *ptrToHeadPtr = node;
    return node;
}

Node *insertFirst(Node **ptrToHeadPtr, int val)
{
    Node *node = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    node->value = val;
    node->link = *ptrToHeadPtr;
    *ptrToHeadPtr = node;
    return node;
}
void traverse(Node *p)
{
    while (p != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d ", p->value);
        p = p->link;
    }
}

void freeList(Node *p)
{
    Node *temp;
    while (p != NULL)
    {
        temp = p;
        p = p->link;
        free(temp);
    }
}

int main()
{
    Node *HeadPtr = NULL;
    int j;

    printf("Now creating list with \"Insert in Front\" method: \n\n");
    for (j = 0; j < 13; j++){
        insertFirst(&HeadPtr, j);
        printf("%d ", HeadPtr->value);
    }
    printf("\n\n");
    printf("Now traversing list created by \"Insert in Front\" method: (HeadPtr is currently: %d)\n\n", HeadPtr->value);
    traverse(HeadPtr);
    printf("\n\n");
    printf("Now testing \"In Order\" method on list: (HeadPtr is currently: %d)\n\n", HeadPtr->value);
    inOrder(HeadPtr); 
    printf("\n\n");
    printf("Now testing \"Delete from Front\" method on list: (HeadPtr is currently: %d)\n\n", HeadPtr->value);
    deleteFirst(&HeadPtr);
    printf("(HeadPtr is currently: %d)\n\n", HeadPtr->value); 
    traverse(HeadPtr);
    printf("\n\n");
    freeList(HeadPtr);

    printf("(HeadPtr is currently: %d)\n\n", HeadPtr->value);

    HeadPtr = NULL; 

    printf("Now creating list with \"Insert in Rear\" method: (HeadPtr is currently: %d)\n\n", HeadPtr->value);
    for (j = 0; j < 13; j++){
        insertLast(&HeadPtr, j);
        printf("%d ", HeadPtr->value);
    }
    printf("\n\n");
    printf("Now traversing list created by \"Insert in Rear\" method: (HeadPtr is currently: %d)\n\n", HeadPtr->value);
    traverse(HeadPtr);
    printf("\n\n");
    printf("Now testing \"In Order\" method on list: (HeadPtr is currently: %d)\n\n", HeadPtr->value);
    inOrder(HeadPtr);
    printf("\n\n");
    freeList(HeadPtr);

    HeadPtr = NULL;

    int temp;

    printf("Now creating list with \"Insert in Front\" method \nand randomly generated data between 0 and 9: \n\n");
    for (j = 0; j<13; j++){
        temp = rand() % 9;
        insertFirst(&HeadPtr, temp);
        printf("%d ", HeadPtr->value);
    }
    printf("\n\n");
    printf("Now traversing list created by \"Insert in Front\" method: (HeadPtr is currently: %d)\n\n", HeadPtr->value);
    traverse(HeadPtr);
    printf("\n\n");
    temp = rand() % 9;
    printf("Now testing \"count Target\" method on list searching for %d: (HeadPtr is currently: %d)", temp, HeadPtr->value);
    countTarget(HeadPtr, temp);
    freeList(HeadPtr);

    getchar();
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: I would suggest to read about single linked lists. You will find good samples which exactly describe your problem. Hint: Your first problem is that your shiny new list is never initialized properly.

Comment: As he is clearly stating that he is taking a C++ Class I have not edited the C++ tag yet, but I did some formatting to make the question more readable (there were a lot of newlines in the code).

Comment: Wow you guys respond fast here; thank you all for your insights and corrections. The class actually IS a C class but the compiler we use is a C++ compiler ( Microsoft visual studio). i should have made that clear my apologies; I will make all these changes when I get home. if anyone has any more insights or corrections please keep them coming and again thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

`insertLast` the way you implemented it is not `insertLast`, but `insertSecond`. Of course, it would crash if you have no elements in the list, as `insertSecond` is meaningless in that context.
To do this properly, you need to traverse the list, determine the last element, and then insert past that element.

`inOrder` accesses `start->value` without checking that `start` is not NULL.

As an aside, this is C and not C++, and there are many stylistic and interface issues that I'm sure your professor will point out.

Comment: I feel like I'm on the cusp of understanding this....i know that what your pointing out is the crux of where I went wrong...thank you...